# any source for the idea that the Baal Koreh represents Moshe Rabbainu?

Tags: torah-reading, moshe-rabbeinu, chazzan-prayer-leader

I have heard that the Baal Koreh represents Moshe Rabbeinu like at matan torah. Does anybody have a source for that idea?

Comment: Yerushalmi Megillah 4:1

Comment: Thanks.  Does that source include the idea that one of the Gabbaim represents G-d? (I heard that from a very religious orthodox rabbi, and he said so the gabba is adjacent to the baal koreh). I'm particularly interested in what the source for that is. He said one gabba has the cards deciding who is to be called up and he tells the other gabba who to call up. And one of the gabbaim represents G-d. while the baal koreh-representse moshe rabbainu. be v interested to know if anybody knows a source for that.

Comment: @DoubleAA is that Perek ד? or Daf ד?

Comment: @sanders Perek 4 Halacha 1

Comment: The Shulchan Aruch (don't remember where) requires 3 people for the reading - typically gabbai, baal korei and a  third person. R' Moshe Shapiro cites this in his shiurim saying the underlying reason is they correspond to the 3 parties in the Maamad Har Sinai - Hashem, Moshe and Knesset Yisrael.

Comment: @gt6989b You might be thinking of OC 141:4

Comment: @gt6989b do you have a link to the shiur? or any idea of the title of the shiur - is it online?

Comment: @smu He cites it in his Thursday night shiurim, on a regular basis. I will try to post here to get you a link. The web site where you could get these is http://www.zyapublications.com.

Comment: See Levush 141:4

Comment: @smu@gt6989b Rav Moshes shiurem are also available here: http://www.kolhalashon.com/New/Ravs.aspx?&Lang=Hebrew&Path=Hebrew|HMusar|Sichot|R0027

Answer (score 1):

This Yerushalmi ([Megillah perek 4, halacha 1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r2a04.htm)) that [Double AA cited](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29052/any-source-for-the-idea-that-the-baal-koreh-represents-moshe-rabbainu#comment71453_29052) tells a fascinating story. In it, Rav Shmuel bar Rav Yitzchak visits a shul and witnesses keriat haTorah in which the reader is “leaning on a post.”  He claims that “This posture is forbidden, just as it was delivered at Sinai in a manner which instigated fear and trembling, so must it be rendered in public in a manner which evinces awe.” (Translation taken from a shiur by Rav Moshe Taragin).

Clearly, our keriat hatorah is seen as a recreation and reenactment of the experience of Maamad Har Sinai and the original Kabbalat Hatorah. Therefore, it would make a lot of sense that the Baal Koreh today is seen kivyachol like Moshe, because he is revealing the Torah to us thru his keriah, as Moshe did.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding the Yerushalmi. I understood it, at least, to mean that the meturgeman (translator) is like Moshe because he interlocutes between the Torah reading and the congregation.

Comment: Then what is the role of the Baal koreh, if the meturgeman is Moshe? Does the Baal koreh merely represent klal yisrael in every shul? Also, we don't have meturgemanim anymore, so its a bit of a moot metaphor.

Comment: If the _m'turg'man_ is like _Moshe_ then presumaby the _baal k'ria_ is like God. Some _baale k'ria_ would agree. `:-)`

Comment: see also Shiurim le-Zekher Aba Mari, be-inyan keriat ha-torah.

Comment: @EiluV'Eilu come to me shul we have tarjumon. each and every posuk in the parsha on shabboth there a person leining and another person being a tarjumon. also for the haftoroh each posuk is read twice one with loshon hakodesh and person reading tarjum.

Comment: thanks, the english is very helpful.  there looks to be quite a bit of the aramaic at that link, can you quote an extract of aramaic which you gave a translation of?  I see on that page the words למשה מסיני  occur so I guess it's around there.

Comment: @DoubleAA Is there a very large amount to translate with the relevant part of yerushalmi megillah 4:1 or just a few sentences?

Comment: @DoubleAA also, regarding OC 141:4 (I have a translation of it)  OC 141:4 "If the reader for the community[baal koreh] wishes to say the blessing himself and read, someone else must stand next to him. This is because just as the Torah was given through an intermediary, so we are required to act with it at the reading and we must therefore have it given throuh an intermediary"   <-- howcome the caller upper doesn't count as somebody as an intermediary? i.e. it needs a sgun/deputy gabba?